ETag missing in Google Sheets API GET request
When using the Google Sheets API - spreadsheets/get (docs) I don't see any ETag value, but it seems that it CAN be in the APIs:
var sheet = test.Spreadsheets.Get("1WC7CGN****************************nw");
sheet.IncludeGridData = false;
var sheetResponse = await sheet.ExecuteAsync();
var etag = sheetResponse.ETag;

But it's always null.
Was expecting there to be an ETag, so I can check if data has changed.
